# Publishing a story using Facebook open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently trying to run through the publish open graph story for iOS tutorial on the Facebook website.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/

I'm getting lost at step 2 - Set up your back end server. I have set up a Heroku account just like it says and I go through the set up tutorial on the Heroku site. It all seems fine. I save the code listed in step 2 in a new file I created called opengraphobject.php (I have no idea if this was the right thing to do?).

After that it says "Once you've uploaded the dynamic object creation code, test a sample object using the Object Debugger. Enter a URL into the debugger, for example:"

```
https://fbsdkog.herokuapp.com/repeater.php?fb:app_id=233936543368280
&og:type=fb_sample_scrumps:meal
&og:title=Pizza
&og:description="Pizza"
&og:image=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fimages%2Fdevsite%2Fattachment_blank.png
&body=Pizza
```

I have no idea what I'm supposed to do at this point. My action is called beats and the object is called boss. How do I generate a url like this for my own action?

I can't move onto stop 3 till I move past this because it's very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page `opengraphobject.php` should contain the sample code provided in that step.

So when you are done setting it up you point to your url in the debugger to test

```
https://YOUR.herokuapp.com/opengraphobject.php?fb:app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&og:type=fb_sample_scrumps:meal
&og:title=Pizza
&og:description="Pizza"
&og:image=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fimages%2Fdevsite%2Fattachment_blank.png
&body=Pizza
```

Comment: Of course that makes sense. Should I replace the fb_sample_scrumps:meal with mynamespace:myaction? I tried pasting it into the object debugger with and without and it's giving me several warnings saying a description and title should be provided. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @Tiddly yes you need to replace it with your data, if it gives you warnings it means your dynamic php file (opengraphobject.php) isn't working properly.

Comment: Weird, my text editor was doing something funky that was adding a bunch of random characters to the file when I save it as a php file. I've switched editors and now it's saved correctly (is identical to the code int he FB tutorial). I'm still hitting the same issue when I paste the url into the object debugger tho :(

Comment: https://hidden-castle-7245.herokuapp.com/opengraphobject.php?fb:app_id=554329451276476&og:type=gopiratestd:beat&og:title=Beat&og:description="Beat"&og:image=http://pubpages.unh.edu/~chf34/projectcat.jpg&body=Beat

Comment: @Tiddly yeah that's definitely not set up right. you need to convert `&lt;` to `<`

Comment: Awesome, that worked. The object debugger now returns the link successful. It's weird that that error is in the facebook documentation. Thank you :)

Comment: I stumbled very quickly into a new but related problem you might be able to help me with, I've posted it as a separate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209975/facebook-open-graph-graphmethodexception-error-code-100