# Facebook open graph GraphMethodException error code 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to work my way through the Facebook tutorial publish and open graph story for iOS, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/

Step 3 is failing for me. When I use the graph API explorer I get the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I've looked through a bunch of answers on stack overflow relating to this error but none seem to be my problem. I have selected get access token and have publish permissions. The page is not alcohol related and the user page I'm using is not age restricted.

I have selected my application from the top of the page. I have selected post and then entered my story object in the space provided me/gopiratestd:boss

then I add a new field and use the key beat on the left and then the following url on the right.
https://hidden-castle-7245.herokuapp.com/opengraphobject.php?fb:app_id=554329451276476&og:type=gopiratestd:boss&og:title= beataboss&og:description=%22Beat%22&og:image=http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/beautiful_cat_picture_6_168770.jpg&body=Beat

Then when I hit submit it returns that error.

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong here?

When I use that link in the object debugger it doesn't return any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error 100 means that there is a plain syntax error in the URL you are posting to.

I suspect you have a custom graph url set which doesn't match your action - see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-action-types :

> **Graph API URL** This customizes the exact endpoint used when publishing actions, which by default for custom action types is /me/{app-namespace}:{action-type-name}.

Comment: The syntax I'm using is exactly the same as whats used in the Facebook documentation I linked. What do you mean by /{user_id}/feed? For the post url I'm using /me/myappidentifier:myactionname. I've tried replacing the me with my facebook user id but it still give the same error either way.

Comment: I suspect you have a custom graph url set which doesn't match your action - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-action-types/

`Graph API URL
This customizes the exact endpoint used when publishing actions, which by default for custom action types is /me/{app-namespace}:{action-type-name}.`

Comment: Yup I was using the action name everywhere instead of the action object. Cheers for the help.

Comment: You should edit this answer to include the comment you added which solved the issue

Comment: @ReubenThompson please elaborate your answer I am dying to solve this problem. I am using following code `FB.api("/" + objMe.id + "/posts", "POST", {
                        "message": "This is a test message"
                    }, function (response) {
                        debugger;
                                            });` and having the error in `response`

Comment: Different issue - but I suspect that you don't have objMe.id defined correctly. Can you post your full code as a new question and I'll take a look?

Comment: i am also facing "code": 100. if i use the AccessToken from the facebook developer's tools  then it is not showing. If i use the AccessToken which is  generated  from my app. Then it showing that issue. please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Your action is beat, your object type is boss so it should be

`me/gopiratestd:beat`

and

`boss=https://hidden-castle-7245.herokuapp.com/opengraphobject.php?fb:app_id=554329451276476&og:type=gopiratestd:boss&og:title= beataboss&og:description=%22Beat%22&og:image=http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/beautiful_cat_picture_6_168770.jpg&body=Beat`

Answer (score 2):

this error means that your Facebook page setting is not set to visible.

Go to Facebook general setting and check page visibility.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Comment: it don't help me dude. I am facing issue with accestoken.

Comment: Not true, visible group still got this error

Answer (score -1):

Latest response from Facebook:

This is by design and indeed due to the fact that a particular user opted out of platform in their settings. They can still post to a page's wall, viewable on the site (but not via the Graph API).

To prevent user's who opt-out from being able to post to your wall, the page's settings need to be updated to set PLATFORM_OPTOUTS_CAN_POST to "false." The relevant documentation can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#settings

The list of settings for a page can be accessed at this endpoint using a page access token: [PAGE_ID]/settings

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/155412377991372

Comment: This is not the correct answer to the OP's question. Your answer refers to trying to retrieve page posts made by user who has blocked API access to their data

Answer (score -3):

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "CjRXFGNtROl"
   }
}`

If this your error it is because of in correct token. It may be because you are using different account for configuring web app and mobile app for Facebook configuration. Both accounts should be same.

**The app ID must be the same for your mobile app and your web app.**